# How to stop flashing when using frame

Tags: java, frame

I'm trying to draw multiple moving images from arrays, but the screen flashes a lot.

Here is my paint class:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        if (fire [i] == true)
        {
            g.drawImage (missile [i], xm [i], ym [i], null);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        if (enemytf [i] == true)
        {
            g.drawImage (enemy [i], xe [i], ye [i], null);
        }
    }
    g.drawImage (character, xc, yc, null);
}
```

Comment: Create some buffer to create image that will be used in drawImage method. It's the simplest solution. There is a sample solution: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/BufferedAnimationDemo.htm

Comment: Swing already uses double buffering, so all you need to do is extend JPanel instead of Frame and override paintComponent() instead of paint(). Swing will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the flicker, you'll want to *double buffer*. This means that for each animation cycle, you do your drawing into an *offscreen* buffer, then copy that offscreen buffer to the display (wiki article on double buffering [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)).

A simple (untested) example using your code to get you started:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    Image buffer = createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    Graphics ig = buffer.getGraphics();


    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        if (fire [i] == true)
        {
            ig.drawImage(missile [i], xm [i], ym [i], null);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        if (enemytf [i] == true)
        {
            ig.drawImage(enemy [i], xe [i], ye [i], null);
        }
    }

    ig.drawImage(character, xc, yc, null);

    g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
}
```

If you can use Swing, it will support double-buffering behind the scenes, by some combination of:

1. extending `JPanel` and over-riding `paintComponent`
2. setting `JPanel.setDoubleBuffered(true);`.

It's been some time since I've double-buffered using Swing so I'm not certain on the details. A comment to your post suggests it's as simple as #1.

Comment: Swing already uses double buffering, so all the OP needs to do is extend JPanel and override paintComponent(). Swing will handle the rest.